# save expression in variable php

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to store expression in variable and then use it in array_filter to return data  based on this value for example

```
$condition = '== 100';

    $test = array_filter($last,function ($data)use ($condition){
            return  $data['rating'] .$condition;
    });

 var_dump($test);
```

I tried to use `html_entity_decode($condition, ENT_QUOTES);`  `preg_replace( )` `str_replace()` as well as trim  in order to remove the single quotes but  it didn't work

I have many condition and I don't want to write `array_filter` many times is there a way to do this ? or better way then the one I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Show what you tried. What do you mean by "nothing worked"? Please share a code snippet via, say, http://ideone.com or https://3v4l.org/

Comment: "something like this". What does "this" mean? It's not immediately clear from the code what your actual goal is. Where does preg_replace and str_replace come into it? Show what you tried and explain what failed. Be clear about what you want to achieve. Use examples of input and expected output, if it makes it easier. The question is very unclear currently.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: The only thing I can say makes some sort of sense is " I don't want to write array_filter many times"...if you have many conditions that you want to input into the array_filter function one after another, then maybe put them in an array and loop through them? Or write a wrapper function around this code that you can call repeatedly with different input? Is that what you mean?

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it's clear now.

Comment: @Devon I already tried eval and I get this error  when use it " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '==' (T_IS_EQUAL), expecting end of file",||| code = "return  $data['rating'] .   eval($condition)  ;"

Comment: @Eleganceaccessory that's not how you use eval, it has to be valid PHP.

Comment: `eval()` is something you should use with care, especially when you allow user input. Similar considerations are valid when accepting a user-written condition in general. Would it be possible to describe your conditions as a combination of a *comparison operator* and a *value*? In that case you could provide these two criteria in two variables and construct a test inside your comarison function.

Comment: all I want to so is to pass expression using variable, so I can change the condition as match as I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that you have a limited number of comparison operators you are considering. For reasons of simplicity I numbered them `0,1,2,...`. They will trigger different kinds of comparisons inside your filter callback function:

```
funcion myfiltarr($arr,$operator,$value){
  $test = array_filter($last,function ($data) use ($operator, $value){
     $v=$data['rating'];
     switch($operator) {
       case 0: return $v == $value;
       case 1: return $v < $value;
       case 2: return $v > $value;
       case 9: return preg_match($value,$v);
       // to be extended ...
       default: return true;
     }
  });
  return $test
}

$test=myfiltarr($last,0,100);      // test: "== 100"
var_dump($test);

$test=myfiltarr($last,9,'/^abc/'); // test: "match against /^abc/"
var_dump($test);
```

**Edit:** I extended the original answer by a `preg_match()` option (comparison code: 9). This option interprets the given `$value` as a regular expression.

Comment: Nice one since there's no other way to do it.   Thanks